# Selenuim, WebDriver: SessionNotCreatedException: "errorMessage": "Message: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities"

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

So I am using chrome driver version 103.0.5060.53 and chrome version 103.0.5060.114 running on an ECR image based on public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9-x86_64. The error that I am getting with the first code is "errorMessage": "Message: session not created: Missing or invalid capabilities\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}),platform=Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)\n", "errorType": "SessionNotCreatedException"

```html
            chrome_opts = Options()
            chrome_opts.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
            if 'DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG' in os.environ:
                chrome_opts.add_argument('--headless')
                chrome_opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                chrome_opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
                self.headless = True
            chrome_opts.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
            chrome_opts.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
            chrome_opts.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)
            desired_cap = {}
            desired_cap['platform'] = 'ANY'
            desired_cap['browserName'] = 'chrome'
            desired_cap['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'INFO'}
            desired_cap['options'] = chrome_opts.to_capabilities()
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'), options = chrome_opts, desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
```

And with the second code I am getting: "errorMessage": "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

```html
            chrome_opts = Options()
            chrome_opts.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
            if 'DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG' in os.environ:
                chrome_opts.add_argument('--headless')
                chrome_opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                chrome_opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
                self.headless = True
            chrome_opts.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
            chrome_opts.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
            chrome_opts.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)  # Needed for chromedriver 75 (logging doesn't work in w3c mode)
            desired_cap = {}
            desired_cap['platform'] = 'ANY'
            desired_cap['browserName'] = 'chrome'
            desired_cap['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'INFO'}
            desired_cap['options'] = chrome_opts.to_capabilities()
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'), desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
```

I don't know honestly what error is better than the other, I tried to play with many options according to what I found in the web.
Can somebody help me solve this issue and understand it please.

---- Update:
Now I am getting this error after using:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open window in chrome
(Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.114)

```html
            chrome_opts = Options()
            chrome_opts.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
            
            chrome_opts.add_argument('--headless')
            chrome_opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            chrome_opts.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
            chrome_opts.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
            self.headless = True
            # chrome_opts.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
            # chrome_opts.add_experimental_option('w3c', False)  # Needed for chromedriver 75 (logging doesn't work in w3c mode)
            caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
            caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
            print('caps')
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options= chrome_opts, desired_capabilities=caps)
```

Comment: It appears that some of the capabilities you've added are not available.  Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities to find which capabilities can be recognized.

Comment: But here it's like they're using ChromeOptions class instead of selenium.webdriver.chrome.options class to instantiate the options. I cannot find ChromeOptions class in that namespace

Comment: So now I am getting WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open window in chrome (Session info: headless chrome=103.0.5060.114)